# multiauth authentication for api using passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-passport

in my app i am tryinng to create an api for my app it has two user types i.e admin and user i will use two guards one for admin one for user,

i will use passport for this, can you please tell me how to verify admin and user using laravel/passport

i have created guards like

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    admin' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
]
```

can you please tell me about how to authenticate different users using passport package

please share me your idea over this

Answer (score 0):

You can verify admin like this

```
if(Auth::guard('admin')->check()){.....}
```

and user like this:

```
if(Auth::guard('web')->check()){.....}
```